# javascript hours to real hours

Tags: javascript, time

I have a piece of code like this:

```
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);
                                        ^
                                        *
```

I want to know if there is a chart anywhere that can translate js time (*) to real hours, like one hour 2 hour three hour is there any way?

Comment: Check out moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter does not accept hours, you would have to multiply to get it in millisecond.

```
1000 ms = 1 second
60 seconds = 1 minute
60 minutes = 1 hour

2 hours -> 60 min * 2 hours = 120 minutes * 60 = 7,200 seconds * 1000 = 7,200,000 ms
```

The reverse would be a division.

```
3000 ms / 1000 = 3 seconds / 60  = 0.05 minute / 60 = 0.00083 hours
```

Comment: so if I wanted one hour that would be 3,600,000?

Comment: @parseguy yes it is 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 ms = 3,600,000

Answer (score 3):

That `3000` is just expressed in milliseconds, so standard math will do.

3000ms = 3000ms / 1000ms/s / 3600s/h = [.00083 hours](https://www.google.com/search?q=3000+milliseconds+in+hours)

Comment: so if I wanted one hour that would be 3,600,000?

Comment: If you want to express it more readably in code, you could also say `setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 1 * 3600 * 1000); // 1 hour`